# minimal diagram of a knot and the crossing changes

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

Given any knot diagam, we can deform it into  unknot by switching over arc and under arc of some crossings in the diagram. My question is the following:

Let K be a knot a diagram of a knot, suppose the number of crossings need to exchange in order to obtain an unknot is one, then is it true that the knot diagram K is minimal (i.e K has minimal number of crossings).

Answer (score 1):

So, this is definitely not true.  The unknotting number, which you described, is an invariant of the knot.  That means that changing the diagram of the knot you are looking at does not change the value of the invariant.  So, adding crossings by some Reidemeister moves will not increase the unknotting number.  So, if I take any diagram, lets say of the trefoil, and increase the number of crossings by type I moves, it will still have unknotting number one and not be the minimal diagram.

Comment: The OP was specifically referring to the number of times crossings need to be exchanged in a *diagram* of a knot to be left with an unknot. This is not the same as the unknotting number, as that is a minimum over all possible diagrams.

Comment: @DanielRust When you said that $D(K)$ can be unknotted with one crossing change, you mean that the resulting diagram $D'$ will represent the unknot? And if that is the case, adding a nugatory crossing to both $D(K)$ and $D'$ will not change that, and make $D(K)$ non-minimal.  I think I may be confused by your comment.

Comment: Yes, I meant that $D(K)$ can have a single crossing changed such that $D'$ is a diagram of a knot which is isotopic to the unknot. There exists knots $K$ with unknotting number $1$, but also diagrams of $K$ for which no single crossing change will leave you with a diagram representing the unknot. I don't understand when you talk about a 'nugatory' crossing.

Comment: @DanielRust Hmmm, I thought nugatory was a common term. It is just a [reducible crossing](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReducibleCrossing.html). As I said in my answer, adding some obviously reducible crossings to a diagram will not increase the number of crossing changes needed to turn it into the unknot, but it will not be minimal.  Perhaps we have beaten this to death.  Hope this clarified what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $K$ is non-trivial, and let's use $D(K)$ to distinguish $K$ from a particular diagram representing $K$. Let $u(K)$ be the unknotting number of $K$. If $D(K)$ can be unknotted with one crossing change then, $u(K)\leq 1$. If $u(K)=0$ then by definition $K$ is the unknot and so trivial. We've already ruled out this case. It follows that $u(K)=1$ and so $D(K)$ is a minimal unknotting diagram for the knot $K$.

Comment: It's worth noting, but doesn't change the above answer, that there are diagrams of the unknot for which a single crossing exchange leaves the knot-type invariant (for instance give the standard unknot a twist on its equator). The reason this doesn't come into play for your question is because you said "... *need* to exchange in order to obtain an unknot...", and in the above example, the exchange isn't *needed* to obtain an unknot - zero exchanges suffice.